# loopback freeze at Enter name of the directory to contain the project

Tags: node.js, command-line, loopback

I run the follwing steps in command line:

1)npm install -g strongloop
2)slc loopback

The results are: What's the name of your application?TEST

AND AFTER THAT FREEZE

How can i solve this ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [slc](https://github.com/strongloop/strongloop#slc----strongloop-controller) wrapper is deprecated. Use [loopback-cli](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-cli) instead.